# Scalar(0,255,0) does not give green colored line in opencv

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to draw gradient lines on an image. I want my lines to be green colored and I use Scalar(0,255,0). Still, I'm getting only black color. For Scalar(0,0,0) also I'm getting black. For Scalar(255,255,255) I get white, but no other color for any combination. Part of the code is given below:

```
line(visual_image,
     Point(x1*scaleFactor, y1*scaleFactor),
     Point(x2*scaleFactor, y2*scaleFactor),
     Scalar(0,255,0),
     1,8,0);
```

Comment: check the type() of visual_image. if it is 0(gray) , not 16 (rgb) you can't draw colors into it.

Comment: great! that makes sense. Thanks. So is there no way I can draw colored lines on a gray image?

Comment: @HarshWardhan how many channels have a gray image? Then where do you think information about green should be stored?"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

since you can't draw coloured lines,circles,etc into a grayscale image, you have to convert it to 3 channels first :

```
Mat rgb;
cvtColor(visual_image, rgb, CV_GRAY2BGR); 
// now draw your lines:
line( rgb,
   Point(x1*scaleFactor, y1*scaleFactor),
   Point(x2*scaleFactor, y2*scaleFactor),
   Scalar(0,255,0),
   1,8,0);
```

Comment: My mat was bgr and when use cvtColor(visual_image, rgb, CV_GRAY2BGR); gives an exception cause that has 4 chnnels on it but Imgproc.Rectabgle(m1,m1, tlpoint, brpoint, newScalar(0,255,0)) draw a black rectangle!

Answer (score 0):

Just change to `new Scalar(100,100, 0,255)`, .It need 4 parameter for R,G,B, Alpha.

Ref link:  https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc&method=circle

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44352231/7408574

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour),   [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank Shree, I just found the answer and have modified my answer above

Comment: I edit your answer and give a shape as question/answer format.  Please edit your answer if needed.