# OpenCv Core.line draws white when color is expected

Tags: opencv, android

In an `OpenCv4Android` environment, when I create a `Mat` image and use `Core.line()` to draw on the image, it always shows a white instead of the color I specify.

[image: white square instead of green square]

I have seen [a question related to gray scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406368/scalar0-255-0-does-not-give-green-colored-line-in-opencv), but the image I have has not been converted to gray.

```
public class DrawingTest extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final Scalar GREEN = new Scalar(0,255,0);
    private RelativeLayout mLayout;
    private ImageView imageView;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("opencv_java");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawing_test);

        mLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_drawing_test);
        mLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(imageView_dt);

        //test.jpg is in the drawable-nodpi folder, is an normal color jpg image.
        int drawableResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("test", "drawable", getPackageName());
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableResourceId);
        //Mat matImage = new Mat(); // Also white
        Mat matImage = new Mat(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getWidth(), CV_8UC4);
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, matImage);


        // Attempt to draw a GREEN box, but it comes out white
        Core.line(matImage, new Point(new double[]{100,100}), new Point(new double[]{100, 200}), GREEN,4);
        Core.line(matImage, new Point(new double[]{100,200}), new Point(new double[]{200, 200}), GREEN,4);
        Core.line(matImage, new Point(new double[]{200,200}), new Point(new double[]{200, 100}), GREEN,4);
        Core.line(matImage, new Point(new double[]{200,100}), new Point(new double[]{100, 100}), GREEN,4);

        Bitmap bitmapToDisplay = Bitmap.createBitmap(matImage.cols(), matImage.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(matImage, bitmapToDisplay);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapToDisplay);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with the color you have initialized

```
public static final Scalar GREEN = new Scalar(0,255,0);
```

as per this statement

```
Mat matImage = new Mat(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getWidth(), CV_8UC4);`
```

you are creating a 4-channel Mat, but initializing the `GREEN` Scalar with 3 components only, hence the 4th component, which defines the color of fourth channel of your line, which is set of default value `0` in your case.

So, what you are perceiving as white color is transparent in reality. You may fix this either by creating `matImage` with `CV_8UC3` or changing your `GREEN` scalar to be `public static final Scalar GREEN = new Scalar(0,255,0, 255);`